# How can i add url to client browser history?

Tags: javascript

I want to add some url into client browser history (Not current url i mean some additional url)
I didn't find any solution for this

These are some codes i tried them :

```
browser.history.addurl({url: "<http://example.org>"})
```

or

```
history.pushstate(...)
```

But these codes don't work for me and how these codes work?

Comment: The only solution is to open the URL with JS.

Comment: can you explain how i should do it?

Comment: `window.location = "http://example.org";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check those articles ([Using the HTML5 History API](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/)) and ([Adding and modifying history entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries))